# Linq selecting from multiple joins and returning all rows even if a table doesnt return a match

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Consider this structure with 4 tables. childinfo, motherinfo, fatherinfo and guardianinfo.
childinfo table also has motherid, fatherid and guardianid

I am trying to get all data for a child based on ID even if there is nothing in motherinfo, fatherinfo or guardianinfo tables.

My query is like this:

```
 var joined = (from c in _context.ChildInfo.Where(c => c.ChildDob >= dobDtRange.DobStart && c.ChildDob <= dobDtRange.DobEnd)
                          .OrderByDescending(c => c.ChildId)
                          join m in _context.MotherInfo.DefaultIfEmpty() on c.MotherId equals m.MotherId into cm
                          from cmm in cm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join f in _context.FatherInfo.DefaultIfEmpty() on c.FatherId equals f.FatherId into cf
                          from cff in cf.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join g in _context.Guardian.DefaultIfEmpty() on c.GuardianId equals g.GuardianId into cg
                          from cgg in cg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { c, cmm, cff, cgg })
```

This is not working, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You wrote that every Child has a MotherId, How can it be that a Child has no mother?

Comment: Every child should have a mother, however in this system which is run for a foster home, some children may not have mother information or father information or guardian information. So some children may not have any of those IDs.

Comment: So you have a zero-or-one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Yes, not ideal but this is what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a [One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) If your Child has no mother its foreign key MotherId is zero. Some systems have a foreign key value null instead of zero.

To fetch a Child with its Mother, or null Mother if the child has a zero value foreign key MotherId, and similar for Father, etc:

```
var result = dbContext.Children.Select(child => new
{
    // select only the Child properties you actually plan to use
    Id = child.Id,
    Name = chid.Name,
    ...

    Mother = dbContext.Mothers
        .Where(mother => mother.Id == child.MotherId)
        .Select(mother => new
        {   // select only the mother properties you actually plan to use
            Id = mother.Id,
            Name = mother.Name,
            ...
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(), // will return null if there is no mother for this foreign key
    Father = dbContext.Fathers
        .Where(father => father.Id == child.FatherId)
        .Select(father => new
        {   // select only the father properties you actually plan to use
            Id = father.Id,
            Name = father.Name,
            ...
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(), // will return null if there is no father for this foreign key
         ... etc
```